# jQuery fade in div for repeating classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to do something very similar to whats explained in this question - [jQuery hover : fading in a hidden div while fading out the "default" one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170702/jquery-hover-fading-in-a-hidden-div-while-fading-out-the-default-one)

The problem I have is I want to use the fade in/ out on a repeating class, rather than this example which uses a single ID as the selector. At the moment when hovering over my image every other image on the page which uses the same class also fades. Here's what I've got:

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
            <div class="img rounded">
                <div class="post_image"> <a href="#"><img src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2009/07/19/arts/Pool4.jpg" border="0"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post_body hide">
                <p>This is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fade This is a dummy text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="test">
            <div class="img rounded">
                <div class="post_image"> <a href="#"><img src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2009/07/19/arts/Pool4.jpg" border="0"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post_body hide">
                <p>This is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fadeThis is a dummy text to fade This is a dummy text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.test').hover(
        function(){
            $('.post_image').fadeOut(100, function(){
                $('.post_body').fadeIn(100);                         
            });
        },
        function(){
            $('.post_body').fadeOut(100, function(){
                $('.post_image').fadeIn(100);                        
            });
        }
        );


});
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure I need a $(this) in the jQuery but can't get it to work. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use of the `$(this)` object and the `find()` function should work better for you:

```
$(function(){
    $('.test').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.post_image').fadeOut(100,function(){
            $('.post_body').fadeIn(100);
        });
    },function(){
        $(this).find('.post_body').fadeOut(100,function(){
            $('.post_image').fadeIn(100);
        });
    });
});
```